# webp image not loading in browser - what am I doing wrong?

Tags: html, image, webp

I'm trying to incorporate some webp images into our website after following some google page speed insights guidelines.  However, for some reason, it's not displaying the webp image - what am I doing wrong?

I've created a test page to show the issue.  I'm sure it's something dumb I'm doing.  Link here:

https://personalised.clothing/page/default2

The image should be showing here:

[image]

Before you ask, the file is definitely on the server, proof below:

[image]

the code I am using is below:

```
                <picture>
                    <source srcset="/images/banners/Homepage-Banner-1-1920.webp" type="image/webp" />
                    <source srcset="/images/banners/Homepage-Banner-1-1920.jpg" type="image/jpeg" />
                    <img class="banner-image"  src="/images/banners/Homepage-Banner-1-1920.jpg" alt="yazzoo homepage banner" />
                </picture>
```

It's just showing the alt tag - it's not even getting to the img tag, so I'm very confused, as everywhere seems to say that if one images doesn't load, it will go to the next image.  The source domain for the images is https://personalised.clothing

Comment: You mean the one that isn’t actually on the server although you checked? https://personalised.clothing/images/banners/Homepage-Banner-1-1920.webp Maybe it’s got insufficient read rights set so that the server isn’t allowed to read it and the server responds then with a 404?

Comment: Thats the badger, thank you so much.  Solved it by adding .webp as a mime type in IIS type: image/webp and then restarting our server